# How to change cakephp default.ctp layout directory?

Tags: cakephp

Individually I am able to change cakephp default layout by using controller.For example I have used

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout="make";  //here I have changed layout for single action

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //some code...
        } 
   }
```

Here I have changed layout!! But the problem is this layout is not default.I want to apply this layout for all controller.How can I do this?

Comment: do it in your AppController

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your AppController

```
public function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();

    $this->layout = 'custom';
}
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, but in version 3.4 (as i am using) , this is deprecated,  you have to use $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("custom") method to set your layout.

Answer (score 5):

As of CakePHP 3.1, view layouts have changed:

```
// In a controller, instead of
$this->layout = 'advanced';

// You should use
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('advanced');
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer may no longer apply in CakePHP 3.0.5. It requires an event object as an argument in the beforeRender() function.

Try changing the $layout property in the controller itself.

```
public $layout = 'non-default'
```

will change the layout used by all views defined by the controller to src/Template/Layout/non-default.ctp

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3.6.2 you can not use `$this->layout` because is  deprecated. try following code.

```
$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('LAYOUT_NAME');
```